# List items in a template string

Tags: python

I'm sure I must be missing something, is there a way of listing all the templates in an instance of [`string.Template`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Template)?  Or do I really have to revert to regex to find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regex that the template uses and extract the names:

```
>>> s = Template('$who likes $what $$ ${another}')
>>> [m.group('named') or m.group('braced')
    for m in s.pattern.finditer(s.template)
    if m.group('named') or m.group('braced')]
['who', 'what', 'another']
```

The documentation says the regex has 4 capturing groups:

- escaped – This group matches the escape sequence, e.g. $$, in the
  default pattern.
- named – This group matches the unbraced placeholder
  name; it should not include the delimiter in capturing group.
- braced – This group matches the brace enclosed placeholder name; it should
  not include either the delimiter or braces in the capturing group.
- invalid – This group matches any other delimiter pattern (usually a
  single delimiter), and it should appear last in the regular
  expression.

Comment: Nice, was about to comment that it didn't catch the braced, but the update does now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a completely different way to do it (triggered by Lutz Horn's answer but a lot simpler):

```
from string import Template
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(str)
s = Template('$who likes $what $$ ${another}')
s.substitute(d)
print(d.keys())
```

Gives the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This would use a regex, but would this work as well?

```
s = Template('$who likes $what $$ $another')
split_re = r'([$][a-z]+)'
[word[1:] for word in re.findall(split_re, s)]
```

['who', 'what', 'another']

This would extract any placeholder words from a string, excluding any double $'s.